# How to parse \n after joining array to string in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In my Vue.JS code I have array in object which I parsed in string like this:

```js
destination: item[1].destination.join('\n')
```

In `console.log(obj)` I can see it looks like this:

`destination: "test1\ntest3\ntest3"`

But on page it looks like common string, without `\n`.

[image]

How can I parse it to make `HTML` see those `\n`?

Comment: In order to display newlines in HTML you will need to use `<br>`

Comment: Do you want three separate list items or a single list item with three neested items or a single list item with a single element separated by new lines?

Comment: It looks like this - I have array with x elements and I need to do something to show it on page, but every record should be on a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `style="white-space: pre-line"` on your composant html

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of items then
Try following the below approach

```js
let app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
    textData: ['Text1\nText2\nText3', 'Text4\nText5\nText6']
  };
 },
 });
```

```css
.sampleDiv {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="sampleDiv" v-for="(text, index) in textData" :key="index">{{text}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above solution applies for an array of items which you want to be listed on separate lines